# Power bi:Transform list of numbers into list of month names short

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a column containing strings of this format in power bi:

```
6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4
12,1,2
```

My goal is to transform this into month names short, i.e.

```
Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep
Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr
Dec,Jan,Feb
```

I did try a few things, for instance I tried using a search function and concatenate, short sample of this is:

```
    CONCATENATE(
    IF(
        ISERROR(
                search("4",MyTable[month_number_column])
        )=true,
        "",
        "Apr"
    )
```

So I put 12 of those handling all the months and then concatenate all of them together into one, however, there are special cases I can't seem to handle correctly:

the number 1 is also contained in 10,11 and 12, similarly is
the number 2 is also contained in 12, and so my transformation doesn't fully work, and I have tried to account for these special cases with if-tests, but cannot get it right.

Any ideas? Is it perhaps possible to use generate series somehow? Is it perhaps possible to do this?

```
var variable_table = generateseries(1,4)
var add_column_to_variable_table = 
ADDCOLUMNS(variable_table,"Month_name_short",
     "INSERT IF TESTS HERE TO TRANSLATE EACH ROW NUMBER INTO MONTHNAME)
var final_transform = concatenatex(add_column_to_variable_table,Month_name_short,",")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a measure, you can use this below code. As 1 also available in 10,11,12 and 2 also available in 12, you need to transform 10,11 & 12 first and then other numbser.

```
month name = 
SUBSTITUTE(
    SUBSTITUTE(
        SUBSTITUTE(
            SUBSTITUTE(
                SUBSTITUTE(
                    SUBSTITUTE(
                        SUBSTITUTE(
                            SUBSTITUTE(
                                SUBSTITUTE( 
                                    SUBSTITUTE(
                                        SUBSTITUTE(
                                            SUBSTITUTE(
                                                MIN('month value to name'[month value]),
                                                "12","December"
                                            ),
                                            "11","November"
                                        ),
                                        "10","October"
                                    ),
                                    "1","January"
                                ),
                                "2","February"
                            ),
                            "3","March"
                        ),
                        "4","April"
                    ),
                    "5","May"
                ),
                "6","June"
            ),
            "7","July"
        ),
        "8","August"
    ),
    "9","September"
)
```

For **Custom Column** just use **'month value to name'[month value]** in place of **MIN('month value to name'[month value])**

**NOTE:** You can also do some transformation in **Power/M Query**, if you wants the same result from Power Query Editor.

Answer (score 1):

a bit simpler formula:

```
Month = FORMAT(DATEVALUE("2020-" & [month_number] & "-1") , "MMMM")
```

if you want the short form just use `MMM` instead